# Solve this underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I face the following linear matrix equation:

$$ EF \exp\left(T{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -B \\ B & 0 \end{bmatrix}}\right) F^{-1} X_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

where

$$E = \begin{bmatrix} e_{n-1}^\top \\ e_n^\top \\ e_{2n}^\top\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & \dots & 1 && \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \dots & & 1 & \dots & 0\\ 0 &\dots && &\dots & 1\end{bmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2n}, \qquad X_0\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times 1}$$
and $F\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ two symmetric positive definite matrices. $T$ is a real number.

The question is, is it possible to further characterize $X_0$ from this, and how? $E,F,B$ are known matrices, there are $2n+1$ unknowns ($2n$ from $X_0$ and 1 from $T$), so I expect the space of solutions to be of dimension $2n-2$, but how to parametrise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every fixed $T$, you can find a particular solution
$$x(T) = F\exp\left(-T\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -B\\B & 0\end{array}\right]\right)F^{-1} \left(e_{n-1}+e_n\right).$$

Now you know that all solutions $X_0 = x(T) + \sum \lambda_i v_i(T)$ are parameterized by $T$ and coefficients $\lambda$, where the $v_i(T)$ are of the form
$$F\exp\left(-T\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -B\\B & 0\end{array}\right]\right)F^{-1}e_i$$
for $i\in\{1,\dots,2n\}/\{n-1,n,2n\}.$

Comment: Is $E^+$ the pseudo-inverse of $E$?

Comment: Yes. Although you can just replace $E^+\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right]$ with $e_{n-1}+e_n$.